# Searching for a specific string from all PHP files in the parent directory (Updated)

Tags: php, loops, count, themes, frontend

A while ago I made a post ([Searching for a specific string from all PHP files in the parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212892/searching-for-a-specific-string-from-all-php-files-in-the-parent-directory/36213386#36213386)) that was about me finding the position of the file path in an array, only if the file had a specific keyword.

However, that was in my old website, which I have now lost. So I am currently recreating it. However, for some reason this function does not work.

```
  public function build_active_theme() {
$dir = CONPATH . '/themes/' . $this->get_active_theme() . '/';

$theme_files = array();
foreach(glob($dir . '*.php') as $file) {
    $theme_files[] = $file;
}

$count = null;
foreach($theme_files as $file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
    if(strpos($file_contents, 'Main')) {
        $array_pos = $count;
        $main_file = $theme_files[$array_pos];

        echo $main_file;
    }
    $count++;
}
```

}

This function causes the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: in /home/u841326920/public_html/includes/class.themes.php on line 30

I have narrowed the problem down the something wrong with the $count variable. Whenever I try and echo the $count value once the script has found the correct file, nothing is shown.

But after spending nearly an hour on such a simple problem, it is obviously starting to frustrate me, so I am now seeking help.

(Note: I directly copied the function directly from the old post into my code, and made the appropriate changes to variables to 'work' in the new site, so it's is pretty much exactly the same as the solution that fixed my previous problem - which funnily enough was also caused by the $count variable).

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the foreach $key instead of a separate count variable, try the code below:

```
foreach($theme_files as $key => $file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
    if(strpos($file_contents, 'Main') !== false) {
        $main_file = $theme_files[$key];

        echo $main_file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it worked! Thanks! Edit: I will mark as answer once I am able to.

Comment: Side note: `strpos()` could return 0 if 'Main' is the first word of the contents. You can add `!== false` to make sure it's really not found, I updated it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the improvement, and have implemented it in. Thanks once again!

Comment: An update for any future users, I recommend changing strpos to stristr to support case sensitive strings (if that's what you would rather support - like me). Unfortunately, I couldn't update the post due to the change not being 'At least 6 characters'...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting 
        $count = null;
, try to ++ it before the
         $array_pos = $count;